# How to check if input string is in correct format in C?

Tags: c

A want to check if input string is in right format

```
"%d/%d"
```

For example, when the input will be

```
"3/5"
return 1;
```

And when the input will be

```
"3/5f"
return 0;
```

I  have idea to do this using regex, but I had problem to run regex.h on windows.

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more details how you tried to use regex and what went wrong when you did.

Comment: In my experience, there are three general ways: (1) ad-hoc: have your own `char *` pointer that you advance along the string, using character comparisons and perhaps `<ctype.h>` or `strtol` to check for what you're looking for; (2) `scanf`, and (3) regex.  All three have their pluses and minuses.

Comment: regex is a bit of overkill for this. Try `strtol`: `char *cp = buf; int lhs = strtol(cp,&cp,10); if (*cp != '/') return 0; ++cp; int rhs = strtol(cp,&cp,10); if (*cp != 0) return 0; return 1;` You can also check `errno` after each call.

Comment: Or, using `ctype.h` primitives: `int hasdig = 0; for (cp = buf;  *cp != 0;  ++cp) { if (! isdigit(*cp)) break; hasdig = 1; } if ((*cp != '/') || (! hasdig)) return 0; ++cp; hasdig = 0; for (;  *cp != 0;  ++cp) { if (! isdigit(*cp)) break; hasdig = 1; } if ((*cp != 0) || (! hasdig)) return 0; return 1;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear what you mean by the *format* `"%d/%d"`.

If you mean that the string should be parsed exactly as if by `sscanf()`, allowing for 2 decimal numbers separated by a `/`, each possibly preceded by white space and an optional sign, you can use `sscanf()` this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int has_valid_format(const char *s) {
    int x, y;
    char c;
    return sscanf(s, "%d/%d%c", &x, &y, &c) == 2;
}
```

If the format is correct, `sscanf()` will parse both integers separated by a '/' but not the extra character, thus return `2`, the number of successful conversions.

Here is an alternative approach suggested by *Jonathan Leffler*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int has_valid_format(const char *s) {
    int x, y, len;
    return sscanf(s, "%d/%d%n", &x, &y, &len) == 2 && s[len] == '\0';
}
```

If you mean to only accept digits, you could use character classes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int has_valid_format(const char *s) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s, "%*[0-9]/%*[0-9]%n", &n);
    return n > 0 && !s[n];
}
```

Comment: Another option, not clearly superior (or inferior), uses the `%n` conversion specification.  `int len = 0; return sscanf(s, "%d/%d%n", &x, &y, &len) == 2 && strlen(s) == len;` — well, maybe the extra `strlen()` is a problem, but you could add a space before `%n` to allow trailing space in the input, and this would work easily whereas adapting the answer to do so would be relatively hard.  A lot depends on as yet unspecified requirements.  I note that `"  3/ -6"` would be acceptable with spaces before both the first and second (negative) numbers.  It isn't clear whether this matters either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree... The case of "  3/ -6" is already covered in my answer. There is no need for `strlen()` as you can test `s[len] == '\0'` instead of `strlen(s) == len`. Regarding trailing whitespace, both `"%d/%d %c"` and `"%d/%d %n"` allow it easily.

Comment: There is an advantage with `" %n"` over `" %c"`: when the desired format ends with a non-specifier as in `sscanf(s, "%gC", &temperature)`.  `sscanf(s, "%gC %c", &temperature) == 1` with and without the final `C`.  Although that case does not apply to OP's code, the `" %n"` suffix performs well in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if input string is in correct format ... ?

A simple test is to append `" %n"` to a `sscanf()` format string to store the offset of the scan, if it got that far.  Then test the offset to see if it is at the end of the string.

```
int n = 0;
int a, b;
//           v---v----- Tolerate optional white spaces here if desired.
sscanf(s, "%d /%d %n", &a, &b, &n);
if (n > 0 && s[n] == '\0') {
  printf("Success %d %d\n", a, b);
} else {
  printf("Failure\n");
}
```

Comment: I suppose that if you were worried about leading white space before the numbers or trailing white space, you could devise a scheme like this (gruesomely intricate): `int a, b; int o1 = 0, o2 = 0, o3 = 0, o4 = 0, o5 = 0; if (sscanf(s, " %n%d/%n %n%d%n %n", &o1, &a, &o2, &o3, &b, &o4, &o5) == 2 && o1 == 0 && o2 == o3 && o4 == o5 && s[o5] == '\0') { …OK… } else { …some problem… }` —— but that's pushing the outer limits of sanity.  I've never gone to quite that length before!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sometimes we need to.  ["The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to venture a little way past them to the impossible.](https://www.nsf.gov/news/speeches/bordogna/rochester/tsld009.htm).  BTW, the 5 initializations not needed in this case given the `== 2`.

Comment: Oh, that's clever — I hadn't noticed that.  Yes, you could skip initializing `o1`..`o5` if you don't use the values after the `if` statement.  I checked the code with printing after (a mild variation on) the `if` statement, and could have run into problems with uninitialized values in some of the error reporting if the variables were not initialized.